# Visual Basic: If string is correct, then write something constantly crashed without errors

Tags: excel, vba

I had some perfectly working code, but then I accidently deleted it, so I came up with this from the top of my head:

```
Tabelle1.Activate
Dim i As Integer
i = 2
While i <= 33821
    celltxt = ActiceSheet.Range("D" & i).Text
    If InStr(1, celltxt, " AG ") Then
        Range("G", i) = "AG"
        i = i + 1
    End If
    Wend
```

Basically, it doesn't give me any errors but windows then stops responding.

I have a column (33821 cells) where there are certain strings and depending on that string, I want to write something similar into another cell.

Comment: Move the `i = i + 1` below the `End If`, else you are trapped in an endless loop

Comment: And another thing: write `Dim i As Long`, else you will run into an *overflow error*

Comment: Note: `While...Wend` was superseded when `Do...Loop While` was introduced, aeons ago ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You have an infinite loop.

When you enter your while loop, `ActiceSheet.Range("D2").Text` (presumably) does not contain "  AG ". Because the condition is not true in the `if` statement, `i` is never increased.

Try to add a breakpoint in the debugger and go step by step through the program to better understand how your code works.

Answer (score 0):

No need for a loop at all, this will do what you're looking for:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    With ws.Range("G2:G" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row)
        If .Row < 2 Then Exit Sub   'No data
        .Formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("" AG "",D" & .Row & ")),""AG"","""")"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

End Sub
```